# Something about using inorder traversal prints all the items in the Binary tree

Tags: python, pycharm, computer-science

We don't know how to print in traversal order and also don't know how to print out the result if we enter the binary_str, can anyone help us?

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self , item , left , right):
        self.item = item
        self.right = right
        self.left = left

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
    def add(self , item , binary_str):
        binary_str_itr = iter(binary_str)
        self.root = self.add_aux(self.root , item , binary_str_itr)

    def add_aux(self , current , item , binary_str_itr):
        if current is None:
            current = TreeNode(None , None , None)
        try:
            bit = next(binary_str_itr)
            if bit == '0':
                current.left = self.add_aux(current.left , item , binary_str_itr)
            elif bit == '1':
                current.right = self.add_aux(current.right , item , binary_str_itr)
        except StopIteration:
            current.item = item
        return current


    def print_inorder(self):
        self.print_inorder_aux(self.root)

    def print_inorder_aux(self,current):
        if current is not None:           #if not a base case
            self.print_inorder_aux(current.left)
            print(current)
            self.print_inorder_aux(current.right)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Inoder Traversal, Thumb rule is

```
leftChild - Root - rightChild
```

Follow up on below link [for better understanding](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/TreeTraversals.html)

Comment: @Uncle SAM, for your case golden thumb rule is self.left - self.item - self.right